# NavigationBar's routeMapper is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a very simple navbar I'm trying to wire up. All I want to do is have a navigation bar that shows up at the top of my page (I'll worry about navigating to other pages later). However, when I add the navigationBar prop on the Navigator, I get the error "this.props.routeMapper[componentName] is not a function". If I comment out the navigationBar and do without it, my code runs without errors.

As routeMapper is supposed to be an object, I'm not sure why it is giving that error. My code is posted below. I'm using React Native v21. Any ideas?

```
var routeMapper = {
  title: function() {
    return (
      <View><Text>Title</Text></View>
    );
  }    
};

class TryNavigator extends Component {
  renderScene(route, nav) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hi</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={{id: 0, title: 'My Page'}}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        navigationBar={
          <Navigator.NavigationBar
            routeMapper={routeMapper}
          />
        }
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NavigationBarRouteMapper takes three function arguments:

```
LeftButton(route, navigator, index, navState) { 
  // some component or null 
}
RightButton(route, navigator, index, navState) { 
  // some component or null 
}
Title(route, navigator, index, navState) { 
  // some component or null 
}
```

Try something like this:

```
var NavigationBarRouteMapper = {
  LeftButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    if(index > 0) {
      return (
        <TouchableHighlight
          underlayColor="transparent"
          onPress={() => { if (index > 0) { navigator.pop() } }}>
          <Text style={ styles.leftNavButtonText }>Back</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>)
    } 
    else { return null }
  },
  RightButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    if (route.onPress) return (
      <TouchableHighlight
         onPress={ () => route.onPress() }>
         <Text style={ styles.rightNavButtonText }>
              { route.rightText || 'Right Button' }
         </Text>
       </TouchableHighlight>)
  },
  Title(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    return <Text style={ styles.title }>MY APP TITLE</Text>
  }
};
```

I set up a demo [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/9_1QSA) a while back with the routeMapper working.

Comment: Excellent! I didn't realize that I should implement all three. Turns out the issue was I had "title" lowercase instead of capitalized.

Comment: Ahh. I didn't realize that either!